# Nested ServeMux always returns "301 Moved Permanently"

Tags: http, go

When using a nested `http.ServeMux` to define my server's endpoints, I encountered this problem: the handler would always respond with a "301 Moved Permanently" to any request, even when the URL path should match.

Example:

```golang
package main

import "net/http"

func main() {
    api := http.NewServeMux()
    api.HandleFunc("ping", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Write([]byte("pong\n"))
    })

    root := http.NewServeMux()
    root.Handle("/api/", http.StripPrefix("/api/", api))
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", root)
}
```

When trying to access `/api/ping`, the server redirects to `/ping` (which returns 404, of course).
The same thing happens with any route under `/api/` - `/api/foo` redirects to `/foo`.

I am using Go 1.13 and curl 7.58.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Edit***: to make testing easier in Firefox, I disabled caching.. otherwise I would have to manually clear cache to get accurate results.  I did not seem to have this same issue when using Chrome, though.

[image]

---

Keep in mind I am new to Go but this issue was driving me crazy... I was experiencing the same exact behavior that you are (obviously)..

It would seem Go/http is picky about how patterns are formatted..

I messed with this for about an hour and was finally able to get a working example using the following code:

```golang
// Working Code
package main

import "net/http"

func main() {
    root := http.NewServeMux()
    api := http.NewServeMux()

    api.HandleFunc("/ping", myHandlerFunc)

    root.Handle("/api/", http.StripPrefix("/api", api))

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", root)
}

func myHandlerFunc(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("pong\n"))
}
```

I tried as many different configurations as you can imagine (as far as `/` forward slashes are concerned) and the above code was the only way I could get it to work..

Specifically referring to:

```golang
// Leading forward slash on /ping
api.HandleFunc("/ping", myHandlerFunc)

// The first /api/ is surrounded in forward slashes,
// the second /api only contains a leading forward slash
root.Handle("/api/", http.StripPrefix("/api", api))
```

Changing the code to this causes 404's...

```golang
// DOES NOT WORK!!
package main

import "net/http"

func main() {
    root := http.NewServeMux()
    api := http.NewServeMux()

    api.HandleFunc("/ping", myHandlerFunc)

    root.Handle("/api", http.StripPrefix("/api", api))

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", root)
}

func myHandlerFunc(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("pong\n"))
}
```

I hope this helps in some way! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I was just dealing with this the other day. I think `ServeMux` is expecting rooted trees (starting with `/`) or it interprets the path as a host name.

> Patterns name fixed, rooted paths, like "/favicon.ico", or rooted subtrees, like "/images/".... Patterns may optionally begin with a host name, restricting matches to URLs on that host only.

I speculate that `ping` is being interpreted as a host name and it's causing weirdness in the way the servemux is operating.

In the other solutions that people have written, they're changing around the positions of `/` so that the `ping` route ends up as `/ping`.

Personally, I didn't like that I had to write `/api/` in one spot and `/api` in another spot. In my particular case I decided to using something like:

```
root.Handle(createAPIEndpoints("/api/"))
...
func createAPIEndpoints(base string) (string, *http.ServeMux) {

    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc(base+"ping", func(...){...})
    mux.HandleFunc(base+"another", func(...){...})

    // another buried servemux
    mux.Handle(createMoreEndpoints(base+"more/"))

    return base, mux
}
```

However, if you want to wrap handlers with handlers (like to use `StripPrefix` or other sorts of middleware, this doesn't work as nicely due to returning 2 values.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar issue, but only in cases where you try to define a root path `/` under the nested router.

To deal with it I rewrote my own stripPefix() method as follow:

```golang
package main

import "net/http"

func main() {
    root := http.NewServeMux()
    api := http.NewServeMux()

    api.HandleFunc("/", myHandlerFunc)

    root.Handle("/api", stripPrefix("/api", api))

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", root)
}

func myHandlerFunc(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("OK\n"))
}

// Modified version of http.StripPrefix()
func stripPrefix(prefix string, h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    if prefix == "" {
        return h
    }

    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        if p := strings.TrimPrefix(r.URL.Path, prefix); len(p) < len(r.URL.Path) {
            r2 := new(http.Request)
            *r2 = *r
            r2.URL = new(url.URL)
            *r2.URL = *r.URL
            if len(p) == 0 {
                r2.URL.Path = "/"
            } else {
                r2.URL.Path = p
            }
            h.ServeHTTP(w, r2)
        } else {
            http.NotFound(w, r)
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You're configuring the server but not actually using it.

Since you configured `api`, you should pass it to `ListenAndServe`.

```
func main() {
    api := http.NewServeMux()
    api.HandleFunc("/ping", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Write([]byte("pong\n"))
    })

    http.Handle("/api/", http.StripPrefix("/api", api))
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", api)
}
```

The 301 happens when your `StripPrefix` results in an unhandled route.

Comment: @Adrian OP's code literally has `http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)`. The code in my response behaves as OP expect his to behave.

Comment: Read the line *immediately before that one*. As the question clearly states, `api` is a *nested handler* which is handling the `/api` route in the default mux. Re-read the question and the code.

Comment: The code in your question still configures `/api` on the default mux, then *doesn't actually use the default mux* because it passes `api` instead. The code in your answer doesn't work at all like OP seems to expect based on the question, and it includes pointless extra code to configure the default mux which it doesn't use.

Comment: @MikaelBrenner As @Adrian stated, my original example uses the default mux and the nested `api` mux. When using `api` directly, the server responds to `/ping` instead of `/api/ping`. I will edit my example to use another mux instead of the default one, I hope it will be more clear that way. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Adrian the question was edited: with `nil` changed to `api`